# Halachic Views on Newsworthy Legal Questions

Tags: discussion

A recent Supreme Court (SCOTUS) case, Yovino v. Rizo (18–272, decided February 25, 2019 Per Curiam), took up the matter of a judge that had authored the majority opinion but died before the opinion was "filed".

I had the idea of posting a question asking - for the sake of discussion - what the *halachic* view of the issue would be.  I did not end up making the post, apprehensive that the question was not a good match for this site.  However, I'd like to hear opinions:

Do questions asking for the Jewish (normative *halachic*) viewpoint on questions raised in the Supreme Court, or perhaps lower, state, or foreign courts, have a place on this site?  Would such questions gather interest, or are they more likely to be (zealously) labeled "off topic"?  Should there be a specific tag for such questions?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a question like: if a *beit din* found itself in this situation (describe SCOTUS etc situation), how would the case they were hearing be resolved?  Something like that?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Exactly. In this particular case, I came across _Sanhedrin_ 43a today, which seems to touch on a similar question: What to do if a student judge says he has a לימוד זכות in a capital case but dies before he can express it.

Comment: Consider the entire [tag:current-events] tag. This seems like a great question.

Comment: @DonielF I'll use it in the meantime, but it's not specific enough.  Not for a series of questions with a similar basis.  I suppose if it becomes a habit, there can be a dedicated tag.

Comment: @Menachem I think what DonielF is saying is that we *already* have a tag with a bunch of questions inspired by current events, so there's ample precedent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the characteristics of Judaism that really stands out for me is that thoughtful, well-asked questions that seek to clarify an underlying principle, even if hypothetical, are taken seriously -- in the study hall, in the discussions in the *g'mara*, in modern rabbinic writings.  They should be welcome on Mi Yodeya too.

If a question is about Judaism, I don't much care whether the *motivation* is a text, some practice you saw or heard about, a similar case from outside of Judaism, speculative fiction, or pure curiosity.  (Disclosure: I've asked a few questions that had their genesis in "outside" contexts.)  Questions about how a *beit din* would handle a situation that could come up, and that did come up in some *other* court, fit into that.

Now the caveats: like all other questions here, the question needs to be about Judaism and contain all the necessary details.  For cases that arise from current events, it's even more important to provide details and *durable* links -- that news story you link to today will probably be gone when somebody comes across your question in two years.  A good question presents a Jewish question or problem; what led you to ask it is secondary, so long as you're not looking for *p'sak* which we do not give here.